# Why CUDAImageMultiply so slow in such cases? How can I speed up it

Tags: image-processing, cuda

When I'm  doing Image composition task, I want to use `CUDAImageMultiply` to speedup my performance, however, After trying it, CUDA is very slow, I've tested the following code on Windows 10 and RTX 3060 with 12GB memory.

So,
question 1 is why `CUDAImageMultiply` is so slow, [maybe my using is wrong?]
question2 is how to speed up it.

`ImageAssemble` is designed to compose many images into one image to prevent some IO with GPU by loop, but just failed, so it's not necessary.

The core task is for two image sets[set1=10000 images, set2=10000images], and just do image composition by select two from each set in loop.

```
In[418]:= dims={1078,515}
Out[418]= {1078,515}
In[421]:= water=RandomImage[1,dims];
In[422]:= background=RandomImage[1,dims];
In[423]:= AbsoluteTiming[Table[
ImageMultiply[ImageAssemble[Table[water,1]],ImageAssemble[Table[background,1]]],{i,500}];]
Out[423]= {2.12623,Null}

In[424]:= AbsoluteTiming[ImageMultiply[ImageAssemble[Table[water,500]],
ImageAssemble[Table[background,500]]];]

Out[424]= {4.93865,Null}
In[425]:= AbsoluteTiming[Table[

CUDAImageMultiply[ImageAssemble[Table[water,1]],ImageAssemble[Table[background,1]]],{i,500}];]
Out[425]= {10.5629,Null}
In[426]:= AbsoluteTiming[CUDAImageMultiply[ImageAssemble[Table[water,500]],ImageAssemble[Table[background,500]]];]
Out[426]= {10.1439,Null}
```

This example is in HelpPage, it also shows speed of CUDA is 10 times slow.

CUDALink/tutorial/Functions#488929442

[image]